# Live Templates in IntelliJ Not Working?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-completion

When I create a new Java project and a class for it and try to use shortcuts like `sout +tab`, it just highlights `sout` in red and does not do the println shortcut.

I checked my **Live Templates** settings in **Editor/Settings** but everything looks fine. I've restarted IDEA and created another new Java project and nothing changed. What do I need to do to enable Live Templates?

Edit:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share your Template settings screenshot please.

Comment: edited to include screenshots

Comment: Is it the auto-popup time in your case? I can see the pop-up for the same settings for me. Just a reduced time for auto popup for me. And just to confirm I use MacOSX10.5+ keymap.

Answer (score 6):

If someone still have problem try to define it everywhere
look on below image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your **Code Completion** preferences are checked.

[image]

with **Postfix code completion** somewhat like:

[image]

***Note***: I am using `Mac OSX 10.5+ keymap` as the default keymap for my IDE.

Comment: @usuallystuck have updated the answer with postfix completions used.

Comment: my postfix completions and keymap are the same :/

Comment: @usuallystuck In that case you can probably raise it to IDEA bug tracker.

Comment: i had a feeling it'd come to this, haha. no worries. thanks for trying to help me, though!

Answer (score 1):

Template **sout** is context sensitive. Will not work inside a class you just created.

Define a main method (you can use main shortcut for it). Try **sout** inside the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sout<Tab>
}
```

or inside a static block

```
class SoutCheck {
    { 
       sout<Tab>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlUxb.png)

Turn of the battery save option in file section

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).